# Hitting login url after logging in, in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
 <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">

         <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/register" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/save" access="isAnonymous()" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/login" />
    </http>
```

Above code is defined in my security-context.xml, so after successful log in it is taking me to home page, but after logging in, if through address bar I'm hitting the login url again, then it is throwing 403 error page with description **Access to the specified resource (Access is denied) has been forbidden.**

Please help, what to do?

Comment: Would suggest you looking into Java based configurations.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-secure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the access level to `isAnonymous()` on \login so once you've logged in you have problems as they are now: `isAuthenticated()`

Change login to

`<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />`

Comment: Hey, thanks!!
It worked, I tried again after cleaning work directory and stuff and its working fine, thanks :)

Comment: Hey can you help me out on one more thing, like I have set the default target url as /home after successful login, but its not redirecting me there